# Delete text inside div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, innerhtml

I have an email form using MailChimp and I need to delete the "Thanks for subscribing" message inside a div  after 5 seconds but I can't select the text inside the div.
I tried getElementById, querySelector, innerText, innerHTML, with and without #, but I keep getting null value. 
I also tried querySelectorAll to see all the nodes and it shows the div and id as div#mce-error-response.responde and the text is inside the innerHTML

```
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
    <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none" wfd-invisible="true"></div>
    <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="" wfd-invisible="true">Thank you for subscribing!</div>
</div>
```

```
let myForm = document.querySelector('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form');
let msg = document.getElementById('#mce-success-response').innerHTML;

myForm.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);

function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(msg);
```

That div is being added by MailChimp after clicking submit
Here's the code https://codepen.io/m4573r00/pen/GRpwdKJ

Here's the node
https://ibb.co/gw0jf8J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tried to access the element by using # inside document.getElementById, which is wrong.

You can use SetTimeout function for the delay.

```
setTimeout(function(){
       var el = document.getElementById('mce-success-response');
       el.style.display = "none";
}, 1000);
```

> EDIT

Working code-pen solution based on the comments -  [Link](https://codepen.io/rushabh-wadkar/pen/yLYQZYw)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. I get an empty value. That div is being added by MailChimp after clicking submit.
Here's the code https://codepen.io/m4573r00/pen/GRpwdKJ

Comment: I updated the JS Code - Check this here -  https://codepen.io/rushabh-wadkar/pen/yLYQZYw

Comment: Since the mailchimp is sending out the entire document and loading it in an iframe after the submit, but on submit function was running before it, that is the reason it was returning undefined. So I tried hooking up the element in setTimeOut  function which would basically remove the element if present after 5seconds

Answer (score 1):

```js
let msg = document.getElementById('mce-success-response').innerHTML;
```

not use the `#` or `.` for input parameter for the `document.getElementById()`
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. I get an empty value. That div is being added by MailChimp after clicking submit.
Here's the code https://codepen.io/m4573r00/pen/GRpwdKJ

Answer (score 1):

```
let myForm = document.querySelector('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form');
let msg = document.getElementById('mce-success-response').innerHTML;

myForm.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit);

function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log(msg);
}
```

you need to delete `#` in `getElementById('mce-success-response')`

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. I get an empty value. That div is being added by MailChimp after clicking submit.
Here's the code https://codepen.io/m4573r00/pen/GRpwdKJ